# Read compressed csv file on-the-fly

Tags: ruby, csv, bzip2

I have wrote some csv file and compress it, using this code:

```js
arr = (0...2**16).to_a
File.open('file.bz2', 'wb') do |f|
  writer = Bzip2::Writer.new f
  CSV(writer) do |csv|
    (2**16).times { csv << arr }
  end
  writer.close
end
```

I want to read this csv *bzip2ed* file (csv files compressed with bzip2). These files uncompressed look like:

```csv
1,2
4,12
5,2
8,7
1,3
...
```

So I tried this code:

```ruby
Bzip2::Reader.open(filename) do |bzip2|
  CSV.foreach(bzip2) do |row|
    puts row.inspect
  end
end
```

but when it is executed, it throws:

```bash
/Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1256:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of Bzip2::Reader into String (TypeError)
from /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1256:in `open'
from /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1256:in `open'
from /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1121:in `foreach'
from worm_pathfinder_solver.rb:79:in `block in <main>'
from worm_pathfinder_solver.rb:77:in `open'
from worm_pathfinder_solver.rb:77:in `<main>'
```

**Question**:

What is wrong?
How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the brief docs you'll probably need send the `read` method on bzip2 object (not tested):

```
Bzip2::Reader.open(filename) do |bzip2|
  CSV.foreach(bzip2.read) do |row|
    #               ^^^^
    puts row.inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this is wrong - it should be {{CSV.parse(bzip2.read) do ...}}. And this, of course, reads the entire file into all at once, which is potentially costly - we usually compress for a reason - while other answers seem to allow line-by-line processing without reading the file into memory.

Answer (score 12):

`CSV.foreach` assumes you're passing a file path to open. If you want to pass a stream to CSV you need to be more explicit and use `CSV.new`. This code will process a gzipped file:

```
Zlib::GzipReader.open(filename) do |gzip|
  csv = CSV.new(gzip)
  csv.each do |row|
    puts row.inspect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that `CSV` tries to convert the `Bzip2::Reader` to a string but doesn't know how and simply throws the exception. You can manually read the data into a string and then pass THAT to `CSV`.

Though it's strange since it could handle Bzip2::Writer just fine.